# Can 幸い take a quotative phrase marked with と?

Tags: grammar, particle-と, word-order, quotes

> ここにいたとはあなたは幸いでした。
> It was fortunate that you were here. (given translation)

This sentence looks like gibberish to me. If it is indeed good Japanese could you please explain what とは is doing, and the seemingly bizarre placement of あなた?

I assume it must be some kind of quotative と. If so, does it go with 幸い or is there an implied phrase that has been omitted (I cannot think of anything)?

**Edit**:

So the suggested duplicates perfectly answer the とは part of the question but, as you can see from the comment thread below, I'm still struggling with this sentence.

There is no context; it was a stand-alone sentence. I'm envisaging a scenario where person X rescues person Y from some predicament.

1. Who says this sentence?
2. Who is the subject of ここにいた?
3. Does あなたは belong to ここにいた or 幸いでした or both?

I assume あなたは must go with 幸いでした. To move it after the verb in ここにいた seems too improbable. Therefore I read the sentence as "**You** were fortunate that (*someone*) was here. This means that X is the one saying the sentence, in contradiction to the given translation. A plausible translation then seems to be for X to be saying:

> To think I (X) was here. You (Y) were fortunate.

Another option could be for X to be saying:

> To think you (Y) were here. You (Y) were fortunate.

i.e. if you had been anywhere else then I (X) would not have been in the right place to rescue you. This seems much less likely

The remaining options involve Y saying the sentence.

> To think you (X) were here. I (Y) was fortunate.

This one doesn't seem to work with the position of あなたは, but does match the given translation.

> To think you (X) were here. You (X) were the bringer of good fortune.

This one works with the position of あなたは but relies on a totally different understanding of 幸いでした.

Comment: What do you find bizarre in the placement of あなたは?

Comment: This sentence sounds a little pompous (like an upper class gentleman in fiction), but perfectly natural at least in novels.

Comment: Ah, the given translation is a little off - it's more '*You* were fortunate to be here'

Comment: @Angelos Sorry but I'm still having a tough time with this. I'm now not sure who the speaker is in this sentence. From your comment it sounds like あなた goes with 幸いでした rather than ここにいた, and that seems like the only sensible conclusion given it's position. But does that mean that the person saying this sentence is the one doing the rescuing i.e. "You were lucky I was here". I had originally assumed it was spoken by the person being rescued, as in the given translation.

Comment: @user3856370 The subject of both ここにいた and 幸いでした is あなた. Very literally, the sentence is 'To think that you were here; you were fortunate'. Did the context somehow make it ambiguous who saved whom? Was it a novel or something? It may help us to help you if you post some of the surrounding sentences.

Comment: @Angelos Afraid there is no context.  For the person being rescued to say "you were fortunate" seems rather strange. It sounds as though they think very highly of themselves. "you were fortunate to have the honour of rescuing someone as important as me". Is this really what it means? I'm doubtful. I think it must be that I'm not understanding あなたは幸いでした properly. Rather than "you are fortunate" does it perhaps mean "you are the bringer of good fortune", and "fortunate" is just a really bad translation?

Comment: @user3856370 What do you mean, there is no context? Where did you find this? What were you reading?

Comment: @Angelos Duolingo. It has the Japanese sentence, the English translation and that is all. No explanations, no context. Nothing.

Comment: Read it like "So you've been here, (that means) you were/are lucky!" For example, you may say this when you find your acquaintance is reading a book at a safe basement without knowing the town is being attacked by monsters. Note that this た is [modal-ta](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/another-function-of-the-ta-form-discovery-and-recall/), so it can be translated either as "you were here and you were lucky" or "you are here and you are lucky".

Comment: @naruto Makes perfect sense, thanks. I was picturing completely the wrong scenario. No wonder I couldn't make sense of it.